# HQL case statement in subquery

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm trying to write an hql query with a case statement in a subquery.

```
select zr 
from ZipResource zr 
inner join zr.zipInflows zi 
inner join zi.toInstInflows tii 
inner join tii.toInstance ti 
where ti.state = 'COMPLETED' 
and 
ti.completedDate between :dateFrom and 
:dateTill 
and (
case when :units is not null then
( ti.toPrototype.unit in :units) end ) 
order by tii.zipInflow.zipResource.name
```

Is it real to do somthing like this? On this query I got QuerySyntaxException on case statement.
Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `:units` probably is a set (or sth. like this), because the `in` statements needs a set, if not, it does not make sense. But in the `when` condition `:units is not null` there `:units` must be exactly one single value (or `NULL`), if not it is syntactical not correct.

If you want to check if `:units` is null, then you need a second parameter, for example `:number_of_units`, and you check like

```
and (
   case when :number_of_units != 0 then
   ( ti.toPrototype.unit in :units) end )
```

By the way, your `case` statement is superfluous. You can handle it with a simple `and` condition (which is recommendable because the database better can handle and conditions when looking for search indexes):

```
and :number_of_units != 0
and ti.toPrototype.unit in :units
```

And then there is a even more simple possibility because in SQL `<expression> in (NULL)` evaluates to false. Simply do

```
and ti.toPrototype.unit in :units
```